# String can not be converted to double - wrong JOptionPane for input?

Tags: java, variables

I keep getting the error "String can not be converted to double" I have tried re-defining my variables as int but that doesn't seem to work — I just get a flag saying that loss will occur converting double to int. Im curious as to wether or not I'm using the wrong JOptionPane when calling for input from the user or if my variable declarations are wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package pf_javaass01c;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class ConversionCalculator 
{
    final static String HEADING = "Conversion Calculator";
    final static double CONVERSION = 0.6214;
    final static double PI = 3.14159;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Input Variables
        double kilometers, convertedKilometers, miles, convertedMiles;
        double width, length, areaRectangle, perimeterRectangle;
        double radius, circumference, areaCircle;

        // Kilometer to Miles Calculator
        kilometers = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a kilometer value you wish to convert to miles;", HEADING,     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        convertedKilometers = kilometers * CONVERSION;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, kilometers + " kilometers is equal to " + convertedKilometers + " miles.", HEADING, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         } // End of main

} // End of ConversionCalculator
```

Comment: You've shown quite a bit of code - where exactly is the error? Is this a compile-time error or an execution time error? Please reduce this to a [mcve] (ideally including imports, so we can just copy/paste/compile/run).

Comment: `showInputDialog()` for `JOptionPane` returns a `String`. kilometres is a `double`. You cannot assign a String to a double, you need to convert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value returned by the `JOptionPane` is a `String`. You are trying to put that value into `kilometers`, which is a `double`. You're basically trying to fit a sphere into a triangular hole. As a result, the error occurs.

The solution is to simply *parse*, or convert, the string to a double. To do that, call `Double.parseDouble()`:

```
// get the user input and put it into a string variable first
String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a kilometer value you wish to convert to miles;", HEADING,     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
// parse the user's input and assign the result to kilometers
kilometers = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
```

Comment: @M.deW If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that check mark!

Answer (score 0):

Double.parseDouble() was the answer with new variables that allow for user input to be converted to double!